# Change int value to .00 format

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a dataframe -

```
   year  month             type   amount
0  2019  9          Not Applicable    8000.00       
1  2019  10         Not Applicable    7500.00       
2  2019  11         Goods & Services  14000.35      
3  2019  11         Not Applicable    7500.00       
4  2019  12         Goods & Services  10499.00      
5  2019  12         Not Applicable    9801.00
```

I have column amount fully round of but I want to convert another column month to this format like this -

```
   year  month             type   amount
0  2019  9.00          Not Applicable    8000.00       
1  2019  10.00         Not Applicable    7500.00       
2  2019  11.00         Goods & Services  14000.35      
3  2019  11.00         Not Applicable    7500.00       
4  2019  12.00         Goods & Services  10499.00      
5  2019  12.00         Not Applicable    9801.00
```

How can I achieve this thing.

Comment: whats the use case here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.month = df.month.astype(float)
```

or

```
df['month'] = df['month'].astype(float)
```

Comment: that won't give you two decimal places, just one. Also, the reason why amount has two decimal places is because one of the values is `14000.35`

Answer (score 2):

To convert into float with 2 decimal places :

```py
df['month'] = df['month'].astype('float').map('{:,.2f}'.format)
df['month']
```

**Output :**

```
0     9.00
1    10.00
2    11.00
3    11.00
4    12.00
5    12.00
```

Comment: This doesn't change it into a float with two decimal places -- this just changes the format. A float by definition floats meaning it adapts to the number of decimal places, depending on the values in the column. You can round a float down the total number of decimals, but you cannot round it higher than the total number of decimals for the highest value in the column. For example, you would be unable to `round` the amount column to 3 decimals, but you would be able to round it to 1.

Comment: Ohh alright, I was not aware of that. I'll leave my answer just in case the OP requires it to be of this format.

Comment: Your answer isn't necessarily wrong. It just depends on the OP's objective. Depending on how the question is read, arguably your answer should be the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Terminology is key here. If you just want to change the "format" within your jupyter notebook -- which has no impact when sent to excel -- then @SurajSubramanian 's answer should be the accepted solution. If you simply want to change the column to `float` format, then @nav610 's answer is correct, but the title of your question is specifically "*Change int value to .00 format*"

So, I mentioned, terminology is key, because if you acutally want to change the underlying value to end with .00, then your only option is to convert it to a string like so:

```
df['month'] = df['month'].astype(str) + '.00'

        year    month   type                 amount
0       2019    9.00    Not Applicable       8000.00
1       2019    10.00   Not Applicable       7500.00
2       2019    11.00   Goods & Services     14000.35
3       2019    11.00   Not Applicable       7500.00
4       2019    12.00   Goods & Services     10499.00
5       2019    12.00   Not Applicable       9801.00
```

See my comments on some of the answers for more context, but the answer is that it really depends on your actual use case what the best solution is.